# Generating binary sequences without repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, random

I am trying to generate sequences containing only `0`'s and `1`'s. I have written the following code, and it works.

```
import numpy as np

batch = 1000
dim = 32

while 1:
    is_same = False
    seq = np.random.randint(0, 2, [batch, dim])
    for i in range(batch):
        for j in range(i + 1, batch):
            if np.array_equal(seq[i], seq[j]):
                is_same = True
    if is_same:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

My `batch` variable is in the thousands. This loop above takes about 30 seconds to complete. This is a data generation part of another `for` loop that runs for about 500 iterations and is therefore extremely slow. Is there a faster way to generate this list of sequences without repetition? Thanks.

The desired result is a collection of `batch_size` number of sequences each of length `dim` containing only `0`s and `1`s such that no two sequences in the collection are the same.

Comment: This may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please discuss desired and undesired results. Maybe there is a solution which is fundamentally different.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have added the desired result. I hope the undesired result is clear from the edit I have made. If not, I will add it. Thanks.

Comment: This is very inefficient. Couple of examples - unless you have 1000 unique sequences, you generate new 1000 and start checking again. And the checks - you always check the full 1000 pairs, instead of break out after first pair of same sequences.  There is more room for improvement.

Comment: You probably need to describe more about acceptable and unacceptable results. Because for what you describe it would be a solution to make a list of consecutive increasing numbers in binary represenation and shuffle them. That only gets you exactly the "lower" `batch_size` numbers. But maybe you want to pad so that the last one is `batch_size -1` as closely as possible. I will make that an answer if you do not contradict.

Comment: @Yunnosch, exactly my thought - one possible approach to generate 1000 unique numbers in range(0, 2^32+1) and then convert to desired result

Comment: @buran Thanks. Needs some tinkering for randomisation and sequence-breaking. I had a shot at that in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate `batch` number of `int` in `range(0, 2**dim + 1)`
Convert these numbers to binary, then convert to sequence of `0`a and `1`s.

```
from random import sample

def generate(batch, dim):
    my_sample = [f'{n:0>32b}' for n in sample(range(2**dim+1), batch)]
    return [[int(n) for n in item] for item in my_sample]

def generate2(batch, dim):
    return [list(map(int, f'{n:0>32b}')) for n in sample(range(2**dim+1), batch)]
```

the second one is bit faster

```
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit("generate(1000, 32)", setup="from __main__ import generate", number=100))
print(timeit("generate2(1000, 32)", setup="from __main__ import generate2", number=100))
```

output

```
1.4956848690007973
1.1187048860001596
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but the elements in `my_sample` would have different lengths, right? How do you make sure to prepend zeros so that all are of same length?

Comment: I have suggested an edit with some changes. With those changes, this gets what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I dropped the import unintentionally when editing my answer. `tuple` or `list` - it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

For the described desired result you can use binary representations of the numbers 0...`batch_size-1` (multiplied by (2^dim)/batch_size) and shuffle them.
That approach is much more efficient, because there is no discarding of tentatively generated numbers and the time complexity without nested loops is much better.

For getting a random component into this (not defined for the desired result, but kind of obvious) you can add a random number to each in the range 0...( (2^dim)/batch_size -1). That will not result in identicals either, because of the spacing of the original sequence generated as described above. The randoms will never reach into the range of the next generated number.

E.g.

dim 5, batch_size 8

| sequential | binary | random | total | shuffled index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00000 | 10 | 00010 | 5 |
| 4 | 00100 | 00 | 00100 | 2 |
| 8 | 01000 | 11 | 01011 | 6 |
| 12 | 01100 | 11 | 01111 | 0 |
| 16 | 10000 | 01 | 10001 | 3 |
| 20 | 10100 | 00 | 10100 | 7 |
| 24 | 11000 | 10 | 11010 | 1 |
| 28 | 11100 | 00 | 11100 | 4 |

What remains is shuffling, to break the "continuos run" of this.

Comment: Thanks, but your sequences will always have a continuous run. Suppose I start at `x`, then there will be continuous run (at least) till `x+32`. I am sorry I did not put it in the desired results, but this is some randomness I am trying to achieve.

Comment: In my answer I forgot the shuffling I had in my comment. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to speed up a lot checking for long sequences is using hashing.
For every sequence compute an hash code and then keep a bucket (or a linked list) for all sequences with a given hash.

When you generate a new sequence you only need to check duplicates in the hash bucket of its hash code. For example using 16 bits of hash code the duplication check will be about 65536 times faster.

Comment: Can you share a code sample or perhaps a link to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can get non-repeating random bit patterns as integers using the sample function from the random module.  Converting these integers to bit is a job better done by numpy (as opposed to string manipulations)

```
def sequenceBatch(batch,dim):
    bits  = np.array(random.sample(range(2**dim),batch),dtype=np.int)
    masks = 2**np.arange(dim)
    return (np.bitwise_and(bits[:,None],masks)>0).astype(np.int)
```

This is more than 500 times faster than your function (5x faster than buran's generate2() function)